# Parameterise a URL so that it can be used repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage (static) where I am having to repeat the same URL as a link over 100 times.

Example:

```
Click this link to get help <a href='https://help.service.com'>Get help<a/>
Click this link to call for help <a href='https://help.service.com'>Get help<a/>
Click this link to text for help <a href='https://help.service.com'>Get help<a/>
Click this link to email for help <a href='https://help.service.com'>Get help<a/>
Click this link to radio for help <a href='https://help.service.com'>Get help<a/>
```

It's the same URL. I am trying to see if I can reduce the file size of the html by parameterising the URL.

E.g.

```
Const url = 'https://help.service.com'
Click this link to radio for help <a href={url}>Get help<a/>
```

Is something like this possible using pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much difference this makes but this is kinda what you're looking for.

- Add an `class` of `link` to all the `a` tags and remove the `href`
- Used [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the `a` tags with that `class`
- Loop through all the `a` tags and set  `href` attribute to the URL

```js
const URL = 'https://help.service.com';
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

links.forEach((link) => {
  link.href = URL;
})
```

```html
Click this link to get help <a class="link">Get help<a/>
Click this link to call for help <a class="link" >Get help<a/>
Click this link to text for help <a class="link">Get help<a/>
Click this link to email for help <a class="link">Get help<a/>
Click this link to radio for help <a class="link">Get help<a/>
```

Comment: I'd use a class rather than id (`const links = document.querySelectorAll(".link");`, `<a class="link">`); Ids should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
   var linkTags = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
   var link = "https://linktoyoursite.com/";
   
   for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++) {
      linkTags[i].href = link;
    }

};
```

```
<a class="link">Ask for help</a>
<a class="link">Call for help</a>
```

use a `class="link"` or something like that to all the links you want to be the same.
Then select all the elements like this `var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link")`. This will get you an array of all the link elements. Iterate over the array and change the href attribute of each element.

I put this on the event `window.onload`, which is fired just after the DOM content is loaded.